# ANTLR4 Grammar not detecting fields inside mode properly

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, grammar, lexer

I'm trying to make a grammar to parse easy schema in a structure like the prisma orm uses. After trying a lot of different things it still doesn't parse it properly and I am not sure where the issue lies.

This is the lexer I have written:

```
lexer grammar OrmLexer;

MODEL: 'model';
MODELNAME : LETTERS+;
OPEN : '{' NEWLINE?;

OPENMODEL   : MODEL MODELNAME OPEN -> pushMode(MODELMODE) ;

WHITESPACE : ' ' -> skip ;
NEWLINE: '\r' '\n' | '\n' | '\r';

mode MODELMODE ;
FIELD: FIELDNAME FIELDTYPE NEWLINE;
FIELDNAME   : LETTERS+;
FIELDTYPE   : LETTERS+;
CLOSE: '}' -> popMode ;

fragment LETTERS  : [a-zA-Z] ;
```

This is the parser I have written:

```
parser grammar OrmParser;

options { tokenVocab=OrmLexer; }

start: root | EOF ;
root: model*;

model : modelstart modelbody modelend;
modelbody: modelfield*;
modelstart : MODEL MODELNAME OPEN ;
modelfield : FIELDNAME FIELDTYPE NEWLINE ;
modelend: CLOSE ;
```

I am testing the grammar on an example schema which looks like:

```
model test {
    id test
    user test
}
```

In this schema the fields are not being parsed correctly, there should be two fields namely:
`(FIELDNAME: id, FIELDTYPE: test)` and `(FIELDNAME: user, FIELDTYPE: test)` however it doesn't parse those, this is the tree I get in result:
[image]

Besides that I am not really sure when to use fragments and when not in the lexer.

I hope anyone can help me in finding/solving the issue! Thanks in advance

I have tried modifying my lexer so such that: `OPENMODEL   : OPEN -> pushMode(MODELMODE) ;` and tried many different small changes in both the parser and lexer, the attempt in above code was the one where I got the closest to the result I want to achieve, namely that the modelbody has the modelfields all separately parsed without any errors occurring.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. First, always print the tokens recognized in a loop outside the parser. https://github.com/kaby76/Domemtech.Trash/blob/eb9ac56453cf3f98c8d6d1e3b4d899a0cfa4c3c9/src/trgen/templates/CSharp/Test.cs#L206-L214 Second, `OPENMODEL` rule expects no spaces, likely conflicts with intent of `MODEL` rule.

Comment: Yeah thought so, It's the first grammar I'm making using ANTLR4, tried following examples but the ones I used are apparently not that great then. Thank you though

Comment: All is not lost. The main issue with your grammar is that in Antlr tokens are recognized regardless of the state of the parser, so this won't work `modelfield : FIELDNAME FIELDTYPE NEWLINE ;`, `FIELDTYPE` would never by returned by the lexer. Try starting with this. `grammar Orm; start: root EOF ; root: model*; field: ID ID; model : modelstart modelbody modelend; modelbody: modelfield*; modelstart : MODEL ID OPEN ; modelfield : ID ID; modelend: CLOSE ; MODEL: 'model'; ID : LETTERS+; OPEN : '{' ; CLOSE: '}'; WHITESPACE : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN); fragment LETTERS  : [a-zA-Z] ;`